# How to delete all photos and folders from Google auto photo backup

Tags: google-plus-photos

From my Android I enabled Google to auto backup my photos. Big mistake! Now I want to remove all the photos from the auto-backup folder. However, Google has created some 100+ folders with dates in the auto-backup folder. By default, Google+ only allows the deletion of all photos within one folder at a time. How do I delete all the folder in one go?